# discord.py file append rewrite the file instead of appending

Tags: discord.py

When I want to append something to a file (with the append mode), it just erases everything before writing what I would like to append.

I have an on_voice_state_update event, when triggered, it checks if the user joined a specific channel. If yes: it creates a voice channel with some permissions for the user who created the voice channel. It is also supposed to append to a file called member_channel.txt this: {member.id}:{the_member's_voice_channel.id} but instead of adding this at the end of the file, it first erases everything and then add what I want to add.

Here are the codes:

```
@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    if after.channel is not None and after.channel.id == 1059553884286230608:
        guild = bot.get_guild(966749409314504774)
        everyone_role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, id = 966749409314504774)
        community_role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, id = 1006304076331483256)
        muted_role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, id = 1059109986258653244)
        global member_channel
        member_channel = await guild.create_voice_channel(name = f"Vocal de {member.name}")
        await member_channel.edit(category = discord.utils.get(get_guild().channels, id = 1057730051321372692))
        await member_channel.set_permissions(member, connect = True, manage_channels = True, manage_permissions = True, priority_speaker = True, move_members = True)
        await member_channel.set_permissions(everyone_role, view_channel = False)
        await member_channel.set_permissions(community_role, view_channel = True)
        await member_channel.set_permissions(muted_role, speak = False)
        await member.move_to(member_channel)
        with open("member_channel.txt", "a") as file:                            # THIS IS WHAT
            file.write(str(member.id) + ":" + str(member_channel.id) + "\n") # IS'NT WORKING
        print(f"[{await get_hour()}] {member.name} created a temporary voice channel.")

#then we want to delete the channel if it is empty and equal to a member's channel, and also delete the line in member_channel.txt corresponding to this member and channel
    elif before.channel is not None and len(before.channel.members) == 0:
        new_file_value = ""
        try:
            with open("member_channel.txt", "r") as file:
                lines = file.readlines()
                splited_lines = []
                for line in lines:
                    splited_lines.append((line.split(":")))
                for lines in splited_lines:
                    for line in lines:
                        line.replace("\n", "")
                    if str(before.channel.id) in line:
                        await before.channel.delete()
                        del splited_lines[line.index(str(before.channel.id))]
                        for line in splited_lines:
                            print(new_file_value)
                            new_file_value += line
                            for ele in line:
                                print(new_file_value)
                                new_file_value += line + ":"
                    with open("member_channel.txt", "w+") as file:
                        file.write(new_file_value)
                        print(f"[{await get_hour()}] I deleted the temporary voice channel {member_channel.name}.")
                        file.close()
            file.close()
        except NameError:
            return
```